# Alternating bar colours by group while alternating background colour and maintaining x-axis label order (ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

**General Info**

I am using the ggplot2 package in R to plot some data where I am interested in plotting each row of my data frame as a separate bar using geom_col. Each bar is related to a group that should be plotted in the same colour and on top of that I would like to alternate the colour of the background using geom_rect where the background will span multiple groups.

I have also not figured out how to plot the background without having a separate geom_rect call for each background. In my real example I would need to perform 24 geom_rect calls and surely there must be a better way (see attempt under title "**Example geom_rect in one call**").

**Below is my code on some test data where I almost have it working.**

I am actually quite happy with the outcome but I have two issues.

1. There needs to be a better way of calling the geom_rect call and without loosing the order on the x-axis which is why the solution under the title "**Example geom_rect in one call**" is not fit for purpose just yet.
2. I want to be able control the colour of the bars for each group. Normally I would use scale_fill_manual(values=c("my_colors")) but that overides the colour of the rectangles in the background.

```
##Generate simul data
gene_list <- c("CHEK2", "AML", "TP53", "AKT1", "ATRX", "CDK4")
df <- data.frame(x = gene_list, y = rnorm(6))
df$grp <- c( rep(c(1),3), rep(c(2), 3) )
df$col  <- c( rep(c("grey"),3), rep(c("blue"), 3) )
df_rec <- data.frame(xmin = c("CHEK2", "AKT1"), xmax = c("TP53", "CDK4"), ymin = c(-Inf, -Inf), ymax=c(Inf, Inf), col=c("red", "blue"))

##Reformat order
my_factor <- factor(gene_list, levels = gene_list)
df$x <- my_factor

##Create barplot
ggplot() +

  geom_rect(data = df_rec, 
            aes(
              fill=df_rec$col[1],
              alpha=), 
            xmin = as.numeric(df$x[df$x == as.character(df_rec$xmin[1])]) - 0.45,
            xmax = as.numeric(df$x[df$x == as.character(df_rec$xmax[1])]) + 0.55,
            ymin = -Inf, 
            ymax = Inf)  +
  geom_rect(data = df_rec, 
            aes(
              fill=df_rec$col[2],
              alpha=1), 
            xmin = as.numeric(df$x[df$x == as.character(df_rec$xmin[2])]) - 0.45,
            xmax = as.numeric(df$x[df$x == as.character(df_rec$xmax[2])]) + 0.45,
            ymin = -Inf, 
            ymax = Inf) +

  geom_col(df, mapping = aes(x = x, y=y, fill = as.character(grp)))
```

[image]

**Example geom_rect in one call**

Using the same data as outlined in code above.

Whenever I did try to use the df_rec which has the limits for each rectangle, I loose the order of my labels on the x-axis, control of the colouring of rectangles and can't adjust the geom_rect xmin and xmax position as I did in the code above without it prompting the error "*Discrete value supplied to continuous scale*"

(Edited) I forgot to add that setting the levels of the factors to have the order that I want for both xmin and xmax still does not order the bars correctly.

```
##Reformat order
my_factor <- factor(gene_list, levels = gene_list)
df$x <- my_factor

ggplot() +
  geom_rect(data = df_rec, 
            aes(
              alpha=1,
              xmin = factor(df_rec$xmin, levels=levels(df$x)),
              xmax = factor(df_rec$xmax, levels=levels(df$x)),
              ymin = -Inf, 
              ymax = Inf),
            fill = df_rec$col
  ) +
  geom_col(df, mapping = aes(x = x, y=y), fill = df$col)
```

[image]

Thanks for anyone taking the time to look at this.

Comment: Both plots result in an error for me. For the first the `grp` variable seems to be missing and the second error is `Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (6): fill`. When you prepare an example, you should test it by restarting R, emptying your environment and running again before posting.

Comment: Sorry just realised that I had made an update just before posting which added two columns to the df data frame. Both examples should now reproduce the results as I have edited the code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it in the end. Below is an explanation of how I solved it. It turned out to be quite an easy fix after all.

I do recommend having an in depth read on the aes function used for mapping the data as there is clearly a difference colouring the parts of the plot you are interested in colouring inside or outside the aes function. Unfortunately I cannot give you an exact answer of how aes works but I can inform you on how I fixed it in my case.

The simple answer is. If you want to control the colour of each separate bar/rectangle (as I do in my case) you are better off explicitly defining that as a column in your data frame and calling the fill function outside of aes.

Also if you want to force a specific order of your discrete labels on the x-axis. This can be done using the scale_x_discrete function where you can explicitly state the order by passing a vector with the order to limits as seen in the code below.

**Successful example**

```
##Generat simul data
gene_list <- c("CHEK2", "AML", "TP53", "AKT1", "ATRX", "CDK4")
df <- data.frame(x = gene_list, y = rnorm(6))
df$grp <- c( rep(c(1),3), rep(c(2), 3) )
df$col  <- c( rep(c("grey"),3), rep(c("blue"), 3) )
df_rec <- data.frame(xmin = c("CHEK2", "AKT1"), xmax = c("TP53", "CDK4"), ymin = c(-Inf, -Inf), ymax=c(Inf, Inf), col=c("red", "blue"))

##Reformat order
my_factor <- factor(gene_list, levels = gene_list)
df$x <- my_factor

##Succesful test of barplot in configurations i wanted!!!
ggplot() +
  geom_rect(data = df_rec, 
            aes(alpha=1),
            xmin = as.numeric(factor(df_rec$xmin, levels=levels(df$x))) - 0.45,
            xmax = as.numeric(factor(df_rec$xmax, levels=levels(df$x))) + 0.55,
            ymin = -Inf, 
            ymax = Inf,
            fill = df_rec$col
  ) +
  geom_col(df, mapping = aes(x = x, y=y), fill = df$col) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits=c("CHEK2","AML","TP53","AKT1","ATRX","CDK4"))
```

Thanks to everyone who had a look at this.